# Unable to convert array to generic list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

Hi I got the issue when converting the array to generic list. It thrown error as below. At the class I already return as ToList but why I still occur. I already change the service reference return type to generic list by default is Array but it get System.Collection.GenericList cannot convert to System.Collection.Genericlist. Please help Thanks

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant) Implements IMerchant.GetMerchantList
    Dim ws As New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient

    Dim General As New General
    Dim kWSUrl As String = ""

    Dim endpointAddress = ws.Endpoint.Address

    Dim newEndpointAddress As New EndpointAddressBuilder(endpointAddress)
    kWSUrl = General.ConvertWsURL("App")

    newEndpointAddress.Uri = New Uri(kWSUrl & "MerchantService.svc")
    ws = New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMerchantService", newEndpointAddress.ToEndpointAddress())
    Dim Data = ws.GetMerchantList()

    Return Data
End Function
```

Merchant Class

```
  Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant)
        Dim Db As New TTMSEntities
        Dim Data = (From p In Db.TT_MERCHANT Join r In Db.TT_BRANCH_SETTING On _
                   p.MERCHANT_BRANCH_INTERNAL_NUM Equals r.INTERNAL_NUM _
                   Select New Merchant With {.MerchantID = p.MERCHANT_ID,
                                             .MerchantName = p.DESCRIPTION,
                                             .BranchID = r.INTERNAL_NUM,
                                             .BranchName = r.BRANCH_DESC})

        If Data IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Data.ToList
            '  Return ConvertMerchant(Data.ToList)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

Error

```
The error is Error Value of type '1-dimensional array of TTMS.App.WebSites.Data.Merchant' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TTMS.Web.WebSites.WCF.Merchant)'.
```

Comment: There are 2 problems: first of all, you can't return a `T[]` array when method is declared to return `List(Of T)`. And second one: your `Merchant` class namespaces differ.

Comment: `TTMS.App.WebSites.Data.Merchant` is not equal to `TTMS.Web.WebSites.WCF.Merchant`.

Comment: Post the code for `ws.GetMerchantList()`.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I already updated the code, Please hava a look. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need logic that can map a `TTMS.App.WebSites.Data.Merchant` to a `TTMS.Web.WebSites.WCF.Merchant`, even if they are identical, because they are two different types as far as .NET is concerned.

Something like this:

```
Dim MapppedData As New List(Of Data.Merchant)
Dim Data = ws.GetMerchantList()

For Each theMerchant As WCF.Merchant In data
    ' Do logic here to map each of the fields in the 
    ' corresponding Merchant classes

    ' Add mapped Merchant (Data.Merchant) to the list

Next

' Return the mapped list of Data.Merchant objects
Return MappedData
```

---

UPDATE:

I would recommend renaming your method and class in your WCF service so that they do not match those in your calling layer, like this:

```
Public Class WsMerchant

End Class

Public Function GetMerchants() As List(Of WsMerchant)

End Function
```

Now your WCF service layer is returning an object that does not conflict in name with the layer that is trying to use it. Thus your calling function (`GetMerchantList()`) is now this:

```
Public Function GetMerchantList() As List(Of Merchant) Implements IMerchant.GetMerchantList
    Dim ws As New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient

    Dim General As New General
    Dim kWSUrl As String = ""

    Dim endpointAddress = ws.Endpoint.Address

    Dim newEndpointAddress As New EndpointAddressBuilder(endpointAddress)
    kWSUrl = General.ConvertWsURL("App")

    newEndpointAddress.Uri = New Uri(kWSUrl & "MerchantService.svc")
    ws = New aMerchantService.MerchantServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IMerchantService", newEndpointAddress.ToEndpointAddress())

    Dim MapppedData As New List(Of Merchant)
    Dim Data = ws.GetMerchantList()

    For Each theMerchant As WsMerchant In data
        ' Do logic here to map each of the fields in the WsMerchant class 
        ' to the corresponding Merchant class fields
        Dim theMappedMerchant As New Merchant
        theMappedMerchant.Name = theMerchant.Name


        ' Add mapped Merchant (Merchant) to the list
        MappedData.Add(theMappedMerchant)
    Next

    ' Return the mapped list of Merchant objects
    Return MappedData
End Function
```

Comment: I already try doing as above but it not working. Sorry i new to WCF development. It will glad you show me more details. Thx

Comment: @user3051461 - you have to create a new `Merchant` object and take the property values from the `WsMerchant` object, I updated the answer showing how you could map the two `Name` properties. In some cases the property names between the two could match and other cases not.